# Populating UITableView from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am experiencing a strange issue with this code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    // Configure the cell...
    if (accounts != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Cell: %@", indexPath.row);
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.accounts objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No cells!");
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"No Accounts"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

My table view populates just fine, except all rows contain the first item in my `NSMutableArray`, `accounts`. I am logging the value of `indexPath.row` and it remains at (null) no matter how many values are in the array. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this! I am bonking myself on the head for not finding this sooner!

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [accounts count]; //<--This is wrong!!!
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1; // <--This needs to be switched with the error above
}
```

The above code was the reason why it was printing the same row in my array twice, rather than marching forward in my array.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [accounts count];
}
```

This code is correct and produces the proper result. What a fuster cluck. ^^;

Comment: I was about to say if you're cellForRowAtIndexPath is only getting called once, check your numberOfRows :)

Answer (score 2):

Should be `@"%i", indexPath.row` not `@"%@", indexPath.row`

Also I recommend putting this at the top of your method:

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
```

Then your method looks like this:

```
// Cell Ident Stuff
// Then configure cell
if (accounts) {
    NSLog(@"Cell: %i", row);
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.accounts objectAtIndex:row];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"No accounts!");
    // Only setting for the first row looks nicer:
    if (row == 0) cell.textLabel.text = @"No Accounts"; 
}
```

It's good practice when dealing with table view methods. Try that.

Comment: I made this change and now the NSLog is reporting nothing but "Cell: 0". It's still not marching forward through my array.